# AndroidManifest PER VARIANT?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest

Easy question but after long time of googling I have not seen a good answer.

- I have 2 Built Types: debug, release
- I have 2 flavors: flavor1, flavor2

This will create 4 variants.

- debug + flavor1
- release + flavor1
- debug + flavor2
- release + flavor2

I have 4 google-maps keys which will be defined in 4 AndroidManifest files, one per variant.

I know i can create 'debug', 'release', 'flavor1' and 'flavor2' folders on src containing an AndroidManifest specific file for each Build Type OR each flavor. But this does not address what I need as I need the combination of Build Type AND flavor (=variant).

So how can I can configure gradle to specify a different AndroidManifest PER VARIANT? (please, nor per flavor neither per Build Type separately as all answers I have seen).

Answer (score 3):

After some tests, there seems to be a whole hierarchy of folder names recognized by gradle, including Build Type, Flavor and Variant, where is possible to override behavior. So, in my example, ALL the following folders would be recognized:

- /src/main
- /src/flavor1
- /src/flavor2
- /src/debug
- /src/release
- /src/flavor1Debug
- /src/flavor1Release
- /src/flavor2Debug
- /src/flavor2Release

so I added the 4 Manifests on the last 4 folders. And therefore is possible to refine the files at 4 folder levels: (1) main (2) built type, (3) flavour and (4) variant.